# Multiple ASP.NET validators

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with the following code.

```
<asp:TextBoxEx ID="CompSCEmail" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBoxEx>    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="RegSubmitCompSCEmail" runat="Server" ControlToValidate ="CompSCEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ErrorMessage="(*)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:ImageButton ID="SubmitButton" SkinID="submitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"
Action="Submit" ValidationGroup="submit" runat="server" VisibleOnRecall="false" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="SaveButton" SkinID="saveButton" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" Action="Save" runat="server" Visible="true"  VisibleOnRecall="makerfirst" />
```

I want to validate the format of the email when the user click both "Submit" and "Save" button. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank You.

Comment: what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: The problem is when the user type invalid email address and move the focus to different control both validators fires. Could you explain how to overcome form the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `RegularExpressionValidator` **[ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx)** Property.

On click of both of your Buttons call `Page.Validate("yourvalidationgroup")`.
This way you can validate email on click of both the buttons.

Comment: I have added two RegularExpressionValidator withe two different ValidationGroup. The problem is when the user type invalid email address and move the focus to different control both validators fires. Could you explain how to overcome form the above problem?